# Error while parsing GEO coordinates in a String

Tags: java, parsing, kml

I'm trying to parse a string a in java and this is the error that I get.

```
<gx:coord>10,8638931 44,6106521 0</gx:coord>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10,8638931"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at parser.history.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

The `Double.parseDouble` method does not accept numbers with commas in them.  The input string must conform to the syntax described in the [javadocs for `Double.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).

If you want to parse numbers in other formats, you should look at the `DecimalFormat` class, and specifically its `parse` method.  Depending on the circumstances, you could get a `DecimalFormat` instance from the Locale ... or create it specifically using a given pattern and symbols.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

java uses a **dot** instead of a comma to parse the floating number.

Call

```
String.replace(',','.')
```

before calling Double.parseDouble

Comment: A better way is using the right `Locale` - see comment Fox32 above